# \newmdtheoremenv-environment unnumbered

Tags: numbering, theorems, mdframed

I would like to have a `\newmdtheoremenv` environment without any number, like I get it from `\newtheorem*`. How can I do this?

This is my `\newmdtheoremenv` environment at the moment.

```
\newmdtheoremenv[outerlinewidth=2,leftmargin=20,%
rightmargin=20,backgroundcolor=blue,%
outerlinecolor=blue,innertopmargin=\topskip,%
splittopskip=\topskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip,%
skipabove=\baselineskip,ntheorem,]{schwartz}%
{The Schwartz-space}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the `ntheorem` package in addition to `mdframed` and issue `\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}` before `\newmdtheoremenv`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\newmdtheoremenv[outerlinewidth=2,leftmargin=20,%
rightmargin=20,backgroundcolor=blue,%
outerlinecolor=blue,innertopmargin=\topskip,%
splittopskip=\topskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip,%
skipabove=\baselineskip,ntheorem,]{schwartz}%
{The Schwartz-space}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{schwartz}
A theorem.
\end{schwartz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. - For the record:  if one uses AMS-packages one has to be a little bit careful but this is explained in the documentation of ntheorem.