# Box with dashed border

Tags: boxes, mdframed

How can I modify the definition below to get an unfilled box with thick dashed lines around it and rounded corners? I don't want it to be numbered either.

```
\newmdtheoremenv[outerlinewidth=2,leftmargin=40,rightmargin=40,%
backgroundcolor=gray!30,outerlinecolor=black,innertopmargin=0pt,%
splittopskip=\topskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip,%
skipabove=\baselineskip,ntheorem,roundcorner=5pt]{case}{Case}[section]
```

Comment: For numbering look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79101/92620) as for unfilled i think you just need to remove `backgroundcolor=gray!30`

Comment: @SAM Thanks. Got those... but the thick dashed lines are my current problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get rounded corner you need to load the package `mdframed` with parameter `framemethod=tikz`.
- To get unfilled box you just have to omit the `backgroundcolor` parameter.
- The way i found to get a dahsed line is by using `tikzsetting`, you can also customize the dashed style the way you want with `dash pattern` prameter, for making the line ticker you simply increase the value of the parameter `line width` related to `tikzsetting`.
- To get unumbered theorem environment as explianed in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79101/92620) you need to add the command `\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}` before `\newmdtheoremenv` definition.

[image: output]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}

\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth= 1pt,linecolor= white,%
leftmargin=40,rightmargin=40,innertopmargin=5pt,%
tikzsetting = { draw=blue, line width = 3pt,dashed,%
dash pattern = on 4pt off 3pt},%
splittopskip=\topskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip,%
skipabove=\baselineskip,ntheorem,roundcorner=5pt]{Cases}{Cases}[section]

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{Cases}
A theorem.
\end{Cases}
\end{document}
```

If you are defining several theorem environments which have some common parameters, you can setup default parameter using the command `\mdfsetup{...}` in the preamble and dont worry about duplicate definition of a parameter because the default one (the one in `\mdfsetup{...}`) will be overrided by the one in `\newmdtheoremenv[...]`, at the same time default parameters that they weren't defined in the theorem definition will be inherited.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}

%default parameters
\mdfsetup{linewidth= 2pt,linecolor= black,%
leftmargin=40,rightmargin=10,innertopmargin=5pt}

\newmdtheoremenv{theoremA}{theoremA}[section]

\newmdtheoremenv[linecolor= blue]{theoremB}{theoremB}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{theoremA}
Using default parameters.
\end{theoremA}

\begin{theoremB}
Using default parameters but with a \textcolor{blue}{blue} line color.
\end{theoremB}
\end{document}
```

[image: output example]

Comment: works perfectly.