# Dashed mdfframetitlerule

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, mdframed

I'm trying to get a dashed line for `frametitlerule` under `mdframed`, but the setting appears to be ineffective.  I'm basing this code on the documentation (Ti*k*z example 5), but this question is also related: [Box with dashed border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/317558/17423)

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{fitb}{ m } {
  \mdframed[%
    frametitle={#1},%
    frametitlerule=true,%
    frametitlerulewidth=1pt,%
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=blue!5,%
    apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlerule/.append style={draw=blue,dashed}}}%
]}{\endmdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{fitb}{title}
  hello, world
\end{fitb}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I'm getting:

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the mdframed code in `md-framed-1.mdf` the problem seems to be that in the definition of `\def\mdf@@frametitlerule` the line is drawn as a rectangle, and not a line, using:

```
\tikz\draw[mdfframetitlerule] (0,0)%
           rectangle (\dimen@,\mdf@frametitlerulewidth@length);
```

Adding `dashed` to the style will of course only change the border of the rectangle, which is probably not what you want. I am sure that it should be possible to change this using `\patchcmd` and friends but I am scared about using it on a multi-line command so in the code below I have just cut-and-pasted the whole command, changing only the part of it so that it draws a line of the appropriate width instead of a rectangle.

This still does not quite fix the problem and I found that I needed to put the `\tikzset{...}` outside of the `\mdframed` command. With these changes in place the MWE below produces what I think you want:

[image]

If you don't hack the `\mdf@@frametitlerule` command, as described above, and only move the `\tikzset` command outside of the `\mdframed` command then instead you get the expected result

[image]

That is, you obtain a filled rectangle with a dashed border.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

% change the mdframed definition of \mdf@@frametitlerule so that it
% draws a line rather than a rectangle.
\makeatletter
\def\mdf@@frametitlerule{%
  \ifbool{mdf@frametitlerule}{%
   \vbox{\hsize0pt
     \par\unskip\vskip\mdf@frametitlebelowskip@length
     \noindent\rlap{\hspace*{-\mdf@innerleftmargin@length}%
     \begingroup%
     \pgfmathsetlength{\dimen@}{\mdfframetitleboxwidth
                                +\mdf@innerleftmargin@length
                                +\mdf@innerrightmargin@length}%
     % the following line has been changed 
     \tikz\draw[line width=\the\mdf@frametitlerulewidth@length, mdfframetitlerule]
          (0,0) -- (\dimen@,0);
     \endgroup}
   }%
  }{%
   \vbox{\hsize0pt
     \par\unskip\vskip\mdf@frametitlebelowskip@length
     \noindent\rlap{}
   }%
  }%
  \iftoggle{mdf@notfirstframetitle}%
    {%
      \par\unskip\vskip\mdf@splittopskip@length%
    }%
    {%
      \par\unskip\vskip\mdf@innertopmargin@length%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{fitb}{ m }
  { \tikzset{mdfframetitlerule/.append style={draw=blue,dashed}}
    \mdframed[frametitle={#1},
              frametitlerule=true,%
              frametitlerulewidth=2pt,%
              frametitlebackgroundcolor=blue!5,%
  ]}
  {\endmdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{fitb}{title}
  hello, world
\end{fitb}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Now that we know what the "problem" is we can achieve the desired result by styling the rectangle that `mdframed` uses so that it looks like a dashed line. One way to do this is to use a checkerboard pattern. This produces:

[image]

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{fitb}{ m }
  { \tikzset{mdfframetitlerule/.append style={
      pattern=checkerboard, pattern color=blue}}
    \mdframed[frametitle={#1},
              frametitlerule=true,%
              frametitlerulewidth=2pt,%
              frametitlebackgroundcolor=blue!5,%
  ]}
  {\endmdframed}

\begin{document}
\begin{fitb}{title}
  hello, world
\end{fitb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think there's a way to do this without changing the internal mechanisms of mdframed? If memory serves, you can specify a fill style. I'm looking specifically at 15.5.1 "Graphic Parameters: Fill Pattern" in the pgf manual.

Comment: @SeanAllred My first reaction was, no, this is a "bug" in `mdframed` and you have to hack it but then I thought again. See edit.